# PC slower after clean installing 12.10

Tags: 12.10

I am running dual-boot on my PC. Win7 and Ubuntu 12.10 (formerly was running 12.04). I just did a clean install and got 12.10. I am noticing that my system is running slower in 12.10 and that it was faster in 12.04. Also, when I open up the dashboard, the graphics get messed up and system freezes (graphics also get messed up after resuming suspend mode).

I tried to update NVIDIA through Terminal but it won't update anything...

Please help with these issues as I really just need to solve these issues in order for Ubuntu to run perfectly on the system.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a graphics driver problem. Launch the app called "Software Sources". 
Go to the "Additional drivers" tab and see whether there is more appropriate driver for you to install.

Comment: If this answer was useful, please upvote it and/or mark it as accepted. Otherwise please update your question.